# Iterate and return based on priority - Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a df with multiple rows. What I need is to check for a specific value in a column's value and return if there is a matching. I have a set of rules, which takes priority based on order.

My Sample df:

```
                           file_name    fil_name
0   02qbhIPSYiHmV_sample_file-MR-job1   02qbhIPSYiHmV
1   02qbhIPSYiHmV_sample_file-MC-job2   02qbhIPSYiHmV
2   02qbhIPSYiHmV_sample_file-job3      02qbhIPSYiHmV
```

For me `MC` takes the first priority. If `MC` is present in `file_name` value, take that record. If `MC` is not there, then take the record that has `MR` in it. If no `MC` or `MR`, then just take what ever is there in my case just the third row.

I came up with a function like this,

```
def choose_best_record(df_t):
    file_names = df_t['file_name']
    
    for idx, fn in enumerate(file_names):
        lw_fn = fn.lower()
        if '-mc-' in lw_fn:
            get_mc_row = df_t.iloc[idx:idx+1]
            print("Returning MC row")
            return get_mc_row
            
        else:
            if '-mr-' in lw_fn:
                get_mr_row = df_t.iloc[idx:idx+1]
                print('Returning MR row')
                return get_mr_row
            else:
                normal_row = df_t.iloc[idx:idx+1]
                print('Reutrning normal row')
                return normal_row
```

However, this does not behave the way I want. I need `MC` (row index 1), instead, it returns `MR` row.

If I have my rows in the dataframe in order like this, `...file-MR-job1`, `...file-MR-job1`, `....file-MR-job1`, then it works. How can I change my function to work based on how I need my out put?

Comment: I haven't quite figured out what's wrong yet, but just as a comment, you can make your code a little neater by combining the `else:` and `if` into an `elif` and unindent accordingly.

Comment: @ObjectJosh I think the wrong part is when there is no order of priority i.e. `MC` -> `MR` -> normal the function doesn't work. not sure if this helps to understand. please let me know!